What is the standard ML pipeline for training and testing?
I have a dataframe containing 1324 rows and 28 columns and I'm kinda lost on which approach to go for when training regression models. Currently I perform a data split and run GridSearchCV to pick the best hyperparameters.
Subsequently, I perform a 10x5-fold cross-validation with the best parameters found. But thinking about it I got worried about test data leakage since the grid search and the 10x5-fold cross-validation evaluation have no connection. I don't know how to coordinate the grid search with the model evaluation.
Additionally, I'm also wondering if it's best to evaluate the model with different data splits (cross-validation folds) or do a hold-out test set and test the model with different initialization seeds. I don't have much real world experience so I deeply appreciate if someone could clarify this matter to me.

If you edit your post to tell us some context, what does does your data represent in real life?
